# Having problems linking with v8 on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, embedding, v8

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I've pulled v8 source from SVN, built it with no problems (wich arch=x64), but I still can't compile my project that tries to use v8.
Here is a sample code that produces that same error :

```
#include <v8.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    v8::Handle<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New();
    return 0;
}
```

The linker error I get is :

```
v8test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::Persistent<class v8::Context> __cdecl v8::Context::New(class v8::ExtensionConfiguration *,class v8::Handle<class v8::ObjectTemplate>,class v8::Handle<class v8::Value>)" (?New@Context@v8@@SA?AV?$Persistent@VContext@v8@@@2@PAVExtensionConfiguration@2@V?$Handle@VObjectTemplate@v8@@@2@V?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I built v8 as a static lib, tried both debug and release build, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to v8_base.lib you need to also include v8_snapshot.lib, ws2_32.lib, and winmm.lib.

The sample on the [V8 Getting Started Page](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) can be compiled in a Console Application with following dependencies listed under Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies:

v8_base.lib;v8_snapshot.lib;ws2_32.lib;winmm.lib;(AdditionalDependencies)